# Как нажать на кнопку Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здраствуйте, имеется такая кнопка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу на нее сделать клик, вот код -

```js
chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Выберите файл..."]').click()
```

В итоге имею такую ошибку:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not interactable

Как это сделать? Кнопка кликабельна мышью

Comment: Выведите на печать весь этот элемент прямо из кода. Сравните с тем, что видите в инспекторе. Терзают смутные сомнения, что вы слишком быстро добираетесь до кнопки и в момент обращения к ней она отключена. Возможно, в классах элемента установлен какой-то класс для отключения кнопки в этот момент или имеется соответствующий аргумент тега.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте нажать по name

```
chrome.find_element_by_class_name('ваш атрибут name').click()
```

здесь очень подробно всё прописано https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Попробовал, тоже самое

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что элемент не успевал прогрузиться, поставил 1 сек задержки, заработало все. Спасибо @cauf

Comment: убери паузу пока не поздно) и используй "умные" ожидания, как предложил Вадим выше, через wait.until

Comment: + лучше добавить ожидание загрузки страницы при переходе на нее, а не ставить паузу

Answer (score 0):

если страница не успевает подгружаться пробуй так

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#your selector'))).click()
```